# Subtract Numbers with decimals

Tags: bash

I would like to subtract numbers with one decimal...

I use:

```
awk -F "," '{$4=$3-$2 ;print $1"," $2"," $3"," $4"}' file.csv
```

Now I only get units, I need one decimal, how can I do it?

Input data

```
London,18.2,19,1
Liverpool,6.3,9,3
Manchester,15.1,17,2
```

Comment: Your script has an extra doublequote after `$4`. Removing that, I cannot replicate your problem. I get a single decimal. Note that your script can be written `awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$4=$3-$2;print}' file.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Calculate your answer in print:

```
echo "10.5 1.1" | awk '{print "Solution:" $1-$2}'
```

in your case:

```
awk -F "," '{print $1"," $2"," $3"," $3-$2}' file.csv
```

just checked your code and as ooga mentioned:

```
awk -F "," '{$4=$3-$2; print $1"," $2"," $3"," $4}' file.csv
```

without the " at the end should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` inside `awk`

```
awk -F "," '{printf ("%s,%2.1f,%2.1f,%2.1f\n", $1,$2, $3,$3-$2)}' file.cvs
```

It allows to use a string formatting similar to the one of `C` or of `FORTRAN`.
You can see the `man awk` in *the printf Statement*. An excerpt from man

```
%f, %F  A floating point number of the form [-]ddd.dddddd.  
   If the system library supports it, %F is available as well. This is  like  %f,
   but  uses capital letters for special “not a number” and “infinity” values.  

%g, %G  Use %e or %f conversion, whichever is shorter, with nonsignificant  
  zeros suppressed.  The %G format uses %E instead of %e.

%s  A character string.  
...
```

the output is

```
London,18.2,19.0,0.8
Liverpool,6.3,9.0,2.7
Manchester,15.1,17.0,1.9
```

If you have comma `,` instead of point `.` to separate the decimal part from the integer one, this depends from [local settings](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Locales.html#Locales). You can change them for all your system searching in the option, or for the current shell or subshell only. You can try with

```
( LC_ALL=C ; awk -F "," '{printf ("%s,%2.1f,%2.1f,%2.1f\n", $1,$2, $3,$3-$2)}' file.cvs )
```

The `( ... )` make it run in a subshell so you will not change the value of `LC_ALL` in the current `shell`.

Comment: Or you could set `OFMT`, like `-vOFMT='%.1f'`.

Comment: Thank you! But I have used your code, but I have something rare

Comment: bash-3.2$ awk -F "," '{printf ("%s,%2.1f,%2.1f,%2.1f\n", $1,$2, $3,$3-$2)}' dades.csv
London,18,0,19,0,1,0
Liverpool,6,0,9,0,3,0
Manchester,15,0,17,0,2,0

Comment: The use of `,` instead of `.` to separate decimal and integer part of a number depends from your local settings, relative to language and numeric format. You can see variable that starts with `LC_something` in your shell. Current version of `GNU bash` is 4.3.11.